# Relative path and 'fopen'

Tags: php

I'm writing a simple output buffering cache engine.

Here is the excerpt of the code that get me in trouble:

```
//...

function cache_page($content) {
    $handle = fopen('./folder/cache_file','w');
    //...
}

//...

ob_start('cache_page');
```

The strange thing is that when I use a relative path like './folder/cache_file', fopen fails, returning false. When using a full path like 'C:/foilder/cache_file' or just the file name 'cache_file', everything works great.

This problem seems to be related with the `ob_start` handler function call (cache_page in this case). Of course, when I put `$handle = fopen('./folder/cache_file','w')` somewhere else, for example, just after the `ob_start`, `fopen` succeeds with the relative path above.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on "application path". In which folder is executed your script, what is the value of `ROOT_PATH`?

Have you tried `fopen('folder/cache_file','w');`?

Answer (score 0):

So it works when you use `C:/folder/cache_file` or `cache_file`? That means you are executing the script in `C:/folder/`. Using the relative path `./folder/cache_file` while being in `C:/folder/` means the full path is `C:/folder/folder/cache_file`.

*Relative* means relative to *the current working directory*.